# Random Forest variable importance metric for predicted value

Tags: r, random-forest, cart

Let's say I'm using a random forest in a true/false classification problem.

When I produce a score for an observation is it possible to get some sort of metric of variable importance for that particular score?

I'd imagine this would be based on the observation's leaf locations across the ensemble.

Answer (score 1):

Had you tried the `importance` function of the `randomForest` package?  For example:

```
x <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE,
             proximity=TRUE)
importance(x, type = 2)
# MeanDecreaseGini
# Sepal.Length         9.223181
# Sepal.Width          2.418925
# Petal.Length        40.900372
# Petal.Width         46.665629
```

Comment: That gives the importance for the overall model. My problem is, once you start scoring individual instances, can you get some measure of feature importance by instance? I thought I read somewhere that this might be possible with an alternating decision tree, but can't find the reference anymore.

Comment: how so? Why couldn't you base importance on an observations path through the tree?

Comment: True, but what about an aggregation of the values derived from the paths followed by an observation?

Comment: @Luke somehow, you want to figure out which variables played the most important roles in generating the prediction for a given observation?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I'm looking for.